# Are stiff legged deadlifts and renegade rows enough to fulfill a back exercise requirements?

Tags: back

Particularly over bent over rows, which I don't like doing. And pull ups, which I cant do yet and don't have a bar in any case.

Comment: What requirements are we talking about?

Comment: I believe what Raditz is asking is what are you trying to accomplish for back exercises, and which muscles? There are several different muscle groups in the back, and we don't know what your overall routine is or what you are trying to accomplish. I would also remind you that the Be Nice policy applies everywhere.

Comment: Yes, that's basically it, however I want to point out that there are other legitimate ways to answer my comment. You could be looking just to sweat a lot and feel your muscles burning (don't dismiss this, this is what most people train for). Perhaps trying to fix your posture? Maybe you are going for some actual fitness requirements. Perhaps you're doing resistance training just to help you another sport. Training your back just to compensate for a lot of bench pressing? You could be following some program looking for an actual substitute. And much, much more, but please be more precise.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't call stiff leg (or romanian) deadlift a back exercise. Yes you use your lower back / traps, but it's not a good substitute for a row or pull-up where you train your lats.

It would be better to do inverted rows or dumbell rows in order to become strong enough to do pull-ups.